# Would it be problematic if I adopted my middle name David as my last name?

Tags: names

My middle name is David. If I were to adopt a pseudonym (pen name) where my middle name is used as my last name, would that be offensive or otherwise objectionable to Jewish people?

Obviously someone out there will have an objection to any topic, but I'm wondering if it would be a normal/widespread sentiment that I would be appropriating Jewish culture or a Jewish identity by using my middle name David as my last name. That is not my intent, and I actually wish I had a different middle name so that this wasn't a possible issue!

Oh, and I'm not Jewish, obviously.

Comment: A famous Jew who reappropriated his middle name as a last name was Ovadia Yosef

Comment: King David is equally famous in Christian liturgy as he is in Jewish writings, so I can't see how you would be guilty of misappropriation. Most church services contain at least one or two excerpts from the psalms.

Comment: I don't see how this is [on-topic as about Judaism as opposed to being about Jews](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-topics-are-in-and-out-of-scope-on-mi-yodeya). (cc @dou )

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13266/759 ? @msh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last name David is not uncommon:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(surname)

and belongs to both Jews and non-Jews. I don't see why anyone would be offended if you adopted it.